# Como exibir corretamente dados de uma tabela de datas comemorativas

Tags: sql

## Registtros da tabela

A intensão é trazer os registros das datas comemorativas em um intervalo de mês e dia.

Exemplo: 
*Quero trazer as datas comemorativas que estão entre 15 de janeiro e 15 de fevereiro, porém quando o filtro é de um mês para o outro nenhum resultado é retornado, mas se eu entrar com o filtro sendo as datas de 01 à 15 de janeiro, a **query** me retorna todos os resultados satisfatórios*

`+-----+-----+--------------------------------------------------+
 | Mes | Dia | Descricao                                        |
 +-----+-----+--------------------------------------------------+
 | 01  | 01  | Confraternização Universal                       | 
 | 01  | 01  | Dia Mundial da Paz                               |
 | 01  | 02  | Dia da Abreugrafia                               |
 | 01  | 05  | Criação da 1ª Tipografia no Brasil               |
 | 01  | 06  | Dia de Reis                                      |
 | 01  | 06  | Dia da Gratidão                                  |
 | 01  | 07  | Dia da Liberdade de Cultos                       |
 | 02  | 01  | Dia do Publicitário                              |
 | 02  | 02  | Dia do Agente Fiscal                             |
 | 02  | 02  | Dia de Iemanjá                                   |
 | 02  | 05  | Dia do Datiloscopista                            |
 | 02  | 07  | Dia do Gráfico                                   |
 | 02  | 08  | Carnaval                                         |
 | 02  | 09  | Cinzas                                           |
 | 02  | 09  | Dia do Zelador                                   |
 +-----+-----+--------------------------------------------------+`

## Query

```
SELECT  
   Datas_comemorativas.Mes AS Mes,  
   Datas_comemorativas.Dia AS Dia,  
   Datas_comemorativas.Evento AS Evento
FROM Datas_comemorativas 
WHERE Dia >= '15'
    AND Mes >= '01'
    AND Dia <= '15'
    AND Mes <= '02'
ORDER BY 
Mes ASC,    
Dia ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se isto ajuda.

```
select * from (

select cast('2018/' + cast(mes as varchar) + '/' + cast(dia as varchar) as date) as [data], descricao from @table

) Q

where [data] between '2018-01-15' and '2018-02-15'
```

Usei 2018 para formar a data mas pode usar qualquer ano, é só pra fazer o filtro funcionar mesmo...

Testei aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68b42/2

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando AND em todas as condições, mas na verdade você precisa filtrar se o dia é maior do que 15 apenas quando o mês for 01, e menor do que 15 apenas quando o mês for 02. Tente a seguinte query:

```
SELECT  
   Datas_comemorativas.Mes AS Mes,  
   Datas_comemorativas.Dia AS Dia,  
   Datas_comemorativas.Evento AS Evento
FROM Datas_comemorativas 
WHERE (Dia >= '15' AND Mes = '01')
   OR (Dia <= '15' AND Mes = '02')
ORDER BY 
Mes ASC,    
Dia ASC
```

Outra alternativa utilizando concatenação de strings:

```
SELECT  
   Datas_comemorativas.Mes AS Mes,  
   Datas_comemorativas.Dia AS Dia,  
   Datas_comemorativas.Evento AS Evento
FROM Datas_comemorativas 
WHERE (Mes||Dia) between '0115' and '0215' --filtro no formato 'mmdd'
ORDER BY
Mes ASC,
Dia ASC
```

Comment: Ai quando é de 22 à 28 de janeiro ela trás o mês inteiro

Comment: @Fabricio Neste caso, aonde tem apenas 1 mês, tu teria que filtrar tudo com and mesmo. Tu precisas de uma query dinâmica aonde esses 2 valores são inputados pelo usuário?

Comment: Sim são digitados pelo usuário

Comment: Adicionei uma nova alternativa, utilizando concatenação de strings (já que seu campo não é do tipo data). Dá uma olhada se resolve o seu problema

Comment: Nope, tô quase fazendo uma query dinâmica quando é no mesmo mês eu uso and e quando é mês distinto eu uso or, é muita gambi